# Android Paging with Room Database; RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination

I am using Android Paging with Room Database.I am going to fetch data using retrofit.But I am getting error No adapter attached; skipping layout.I searched a lot but dont find solution for this. Base url is working, for security reason i just hide base url.

```
  private StoreAdapter storeAdapter;
    private Store_ViewModel store_viewModel;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    private static final String URL_DATA="https://xxxx/";
    //insertion
    private Store_Repository store_repository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        store_repository=new Store_Repository(getApplication());

        //adapter
        storeAdapter=new StoreAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this);


        //recycler
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler_store);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        store_viewModel=new ViewModelProvider(this).get(Store_ViewModel.class);


        store_viewModel.pagedListLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<StoreModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagedList<StoreModel> storeModels) {
                storeAdapter.submitList(storeModels);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter);
            }
        });

        getAllProducts();


    }

    private void getAllProducts() {
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_DATA)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        
//calling api
        Api api=retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<List<StoreModel>>call=api.getAllProducts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<StoreModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<StoreModel>> call, Response<List<StoreModel>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        store_repository.insert(response.body());
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<StoreModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something get Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

This is my ViewModel Class

```
public class Store_ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public LiveData<PagedList<StoreModel>>pagedListLiveData;
    private StoreDao storeDao;

    public Store_ViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        storeDao= StoreDatabase.getINSTANCE(application).storeDao();
        pagedListLiveData=new LivePagedListBuilder<>(
            storeDao.getAllItems(),5
        ).build();

    }
}
```

And this is my adapter class

```
   public class StoreAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<StoreModel,StoreAdapter.StoreViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private static Listener listener;

public StoreAdapter(Context context,Listener listener)
{
    super(storeModelItemCallback);
    this.context=context;
    this.listener=listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public StoreViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StoreViewHolder holder, int position) {
    StoreModel storeModel=getItem(position);
    holder.Product_name.setText(storeModel.getProduct_name());
    holder.Product_weight.setText(storeModel.getProduct_weight());
    holder.Price.setText(storeModel.getPrice());
    holder.Mrp.setText(storeModel.getMrp());

}

static class StoreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView Product_name;
    TextView Product_weight;
    TextView Price;
    TextView Mrp;

    public StoreViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Product_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        Product_weight=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_weight);
        Price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        Mrp=itemView.findViewById(R.id.mrp);
        //listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemCLickListener(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }
}

static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<StoreModel> storeModelItemCallback=new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<StoreModel>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull StoreModel oldItem, @NonNull StoreModel newItem) {
        return oldItem.getDatabase_id()==newItem.getDatabase_id();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull StoreModel oldItem, @NonNull StoreModel newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }
};
```

Json Response from Server

```
    {"status":1,"msg":"",
"paginate":{"limit":1000,"PageNo":1},
"data":
[
{
"product_id":23234,
"product_brand_id":130,
"product_name":"Xyz"
,"product_code":"1554729666482",
"mrp":5,
"price":4,
"product_weight":1,
"product_weight_unit":"PCS"
}




,{"product_id":23244,
"product_brand_id":130,
"product_name":"Abc - 100 Gms",
"product_code":"9A","mrp":38,"price":31.94,
"product_weight":100,"product_weight_unit":"GM"}
```

ApiInterface

```
 public interface Api {
    @GET("/get-products")
    Call<List<StoreModel>>getAllProducts();
}
```

Below is my StoreModel in which i am using room database fro creating tables

```
   @Entity(tableName = "store",indices = @Index(value="product_id",unique = true))
public class StoreModel {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int database_id;

    @SerializedName("product_id")
    private int product_id;

    @SerializedName("product_brand_id")
    private int product_brand_id;

    @SerializedName("product_name")
    private String product_name;

    @SerializedName("product_code")
    private int product_code;

    @SerializedName("mrp")
    private int mrp;

    @SerializedName("price")
    private int price;

    @SerializedName("product_weight")
    private int product_weight;

    @SerializedName("product_weight_unit")
    private String product_weight_unit;

    public StoreModel() {
    }

    public StoreModel(int product_id, int product_brand_id, String product_name, int product_code, int mrp, int price, int product_weight, String product_weight_unit) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
        this.product_brand_id = product_brand_id;
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.product_code = product_code;
        this.mrp = mrp;
        this.price = price;
        this.product_weight = product_weight;
        this.product_weight_unit = product_weight_unit;
    }

    public int getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(int product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public int getProduct_brand_id() {
        return product_brand_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_brand_id(int product_brand_id) {
        this.product_brand_id = product_brand_id;
    }

    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public int getProduct_code() {
        return product_code;
    }

    public void setProduct_code(int product_code) {
        this.product_code = product_code;
    }

    public int getMrp() {
        return mrp;
    }

    public void setMrp(int mrp) {
        this.mrp = mrp;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getProduct_weight() {
        return product_weight;
    }

    public void setProduct_weight(int product_weight) {
        this.product_weight = product_weight;
    }

    public String getProduct_weight_unit() {
        return product_weight_unit;
    }

    public void setProduct_weight_unit(String product_weight_unit) {
        this.product_weight_unit = product_weight_unit;
    }

    public int getDatabase_id() {
        return database_id;
    }

    public void setDatabase_id(int database_id) {
        this.database_id = database_id;
    }



}
```

Below is Dao class

```
    @Dao
public interface StoreDao {
    
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(List<StoreModel> storeModels);

    @Query("DELETE FROM store")
    void deleteAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY database_id ASC")
    DataSource.Factory<Integer,StoreModel>getAllItems();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `recyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter);` outside of `observer` because each time data is observed it will set adapter. So, `adapter` is attached to `recyclerView` only once. Like

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter);
store_viewModel.pagedListLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<StoreModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(PagedList<StoreModel> storeModels) {
            storeAdapter.submitList(storeModels);
            //recyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter); 
        }
    });
```

From the API you are not getting exactly the `StoreModel` as response. You are getting another object which is `StoreModel` is a child object. You have to create resposne object like below:

```
    public class ResponseObject{
    //@SerializedName("status")
    //private int status;


    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<StoreModel> storeModelList;

    //getters and setters goes here
}
```

And then your `interface` should be like below as you are expecting
`ResponseObject` here

```
    public interface Api {
    @GET("/get-products")
    Call<ResponseObject> getAllProducts();
}
```

Comment: on Failure is called by setting recyclerView outside the observer

Comment: onCreateViewHolder() returns null, why are you doing this ?

Comment: I forget to mention- return new StoreViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.store_card,parent,false));but still not getting data

Comment: Are you getting response data correctly from API ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHA-Any idea why it is not showing

Comment: I have tested with you PagingAdapter with my api call and paging works fine . I hope you need to check your response object and check database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231496/discussion-between-amol-and-nrusingha-moharana).